# Horizontal streaking and slowness after update

Tags: drivers, display, i915

MSI Z390-A Pro, Intel Core i-7-9700
Using on-chip graphics. Apparently i915.
kubuntu 20.04
After my update the other day, I get, esp. on kpat and libreoffice writer I get horizontal streaks in the top header, the display of the cards pauses, streaked, when moving cards, etc. Worse - on libreoffice, the cursor isn't moving as fast as it was, and the last char in a document, when I pick up writing, is odd, and becomes clear only after I start typing.

I log out at night, and log back on in the morning. It's not as bad in the morning, but by night it gets bad.

I suspect it was the video driver upgrade, but... anyone else see anything like this, and have a resolution or workaround?

Comment: If it gets worse after using it for some time it's very unlikely to be related with software, updates, etc. The symptom suggest hardware problems. You can and should tested it by (1) booting an older kernel and/or (2) a live session.

Comment: I haven't followed up because I didn't think it was worth it. Let's try this: the problem didn't state until immediately after the upgrade. Please show your train of thought for problem resolution that it's got to be the hardware.  No, it's some kde driver issue. And it doesn't get worse in libreoffice, it just stays bad, cursor one char off, slow response.

Comment: Never mind. I seem to have finally identified the problem - in system settings, it was using openGL 2.0, rather than 3.1. Changing that - which is a driver issue - appears to have fixed it.